# Databinding Combobox to XML with SelectedItem

Tags: wpf, xml, xaml, data-binding

XML:

```
...
<importMethod selected="true">MethodA</importMethod>
<importMethod>MethodB</importMethod>
<importMethod>MethodC</importMethod>
...
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
     DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource XmlSettings}}"
     ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/settings/importMethod}" />
```

This works properly and shows the three elements from the xml, it also shows a fourth blank selection that is the selectedItem.  My question is how do I set the selecteditem to the one that has the `selected="true"` ?

I'm also open to restructuring my xml to something that would be easier to bind. Also I'm taking book recommendations on WPF, I'm still trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: Books? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) should be enough really (unless you look for patterns, architectures and "best practices", but i wouldn't trust the books on that either)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably bind the `IsSelected` on the items by using the `ItemContainerStyle`, something like this:

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding XPath=@selected}" />
    </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```